# Connection established, some applications working, browser not working

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, connection

The wifi of the organization where I work stopped working without a trigger. I am able to establish the connection correctly and to use some applications, for example Telegram, but the browser does not work. There appears to be a problem in DNS (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET). Other connections work (such as my mobile phone connection). The "ping something" command doesn't work and returns me "temporary failure in name resolution". I tried also to adding 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to the resolv.conf file but without success.

Comment: how about something like `ping 8.8.8.8`? do you get a response?

Comment: Yes, that command works. I get no packet loss.